# What kind of processes and threads does iPhone OS create when launching an app?

Tags: iphone, multithreading

When an app launches, I assume iPhone OS creates exactly one process for that, with exactly one thread (the main thread). Is that correct? Or are there more threads or even more processes that come along automatically with an launched app?

Answer (score 0):

The whole app launching process is kind of a black box to us developers. However, I do believe that more than one thread will be created, although you shouldn't need to concern yourself with that. Threads created by the system will be managed by the system. If you're writing a multithreaded app, then you only need worry about the threads you create.